# PFQuery where pointer exists

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

I've got 2 tables in my database:

```
Posts
    -    content
    -    user (pointer)
Likes
    -    post (pointer)
    -    user (pointer)
```

I'm doing a calculation on how many posts the user has 'Liked' - but the only thing is some posts don't exist because they've been deleted. So what i'm basically trying to do is fetch all 'Likes' where the posts exist too.

My current query is like so:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Likes"];
[query whereKey:@"user" isEqualTo:self.user];
[query includeKey:@"post"];
[query includeKey:@"post.owner"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a second query targeting the Post class using the [-whereKey:matchesKey:inQuery:](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#/c:objc(cs)PFQuery(im)whereKey:matchesKey:inQuery:) method:

```c
PFQuery *likesQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Likes"];
[query whereKey:@"user" isEqualTo:self.user];
// don't have to include these since this is a subquery
//[query includeKey:@"post"];
//[query includeKey:@"post.owner"];

PFQuery *postsQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Posts"];
[query whereKey:@"objectId" matchesKey:"post" inQuery:likesQuery];
```

Then `postsQuery` will be able give you the number of posts that exist *and* were liked by the user.